# Temporarily remove labels/tags and re-insert them later on

Tags: php

Consider the following string

```
$input = "string with {LABELS} between brackets {HERE} and {HERE}";
```

I want to temporarily remove all labels (= whatever is between curly braces) so that an operation can be performed on the rest of the string:

```
$string = "string with between brackets and";
```

For arguments sake, the operation is concatenate every word that starts with 'b' with the word 'yes'.

```
function operate($string) {
  $words = explode(' ', $string);
  foreach ($words as $word) {
    $output[] = (strpos($word, 0, 1) == 'b') ? "yes$word" : $word;
  }
  return implode(' ', $output);
}
```

The output of this function would be

```
"string with yesbetween yesbrackets and"
```

Now I want to insert the temporarily deleted labels back into place:

```
"string with {LABELS} yesbetween yesbrackets {HERE} and {HERE}"
```

My question is: how can I accomplish this? Important: I am not able to alter operate(), so the solution should contain a wrapper function around operate() or something. I have been thinking about this for quite a while now, but am confused as to how to do this. Could you help me out?

*Edit: it would be too much to put the actual operate() in this post. It will not really add value (except make the post longer). There is not much difference between the output of operate() here and the real one. I will be able to translate any ideas from here, to the real-world situation :-)*

Comment: You need to describe what `operate` does in detail or it's going to be hard to come up with a good answer.

Comment: In reality, operate() is a POS-tagger that first tags the words it has been fed: string/NN with/VB between/VB brackets/NN and/IN (the tags are wring I know, it's the idea that counts here). Then it tags some of the words with fixed characters. The result is in principle similar to what I described in operate() in the OP. The number of words that operate() outputs are the same as what is inputted, but some words will have 'yes' concatenated before them. It is thus possible to find the original input by stripping 'yes' from the words outputted. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this depends on wether or not you are able to **understand** `operate()`, even if you can't change it.

If you have absolutely no insight into `operate()`, your problem is simply unsolvable: To reinsert your labels you need one of

- Their offset or relative position (You can't know them, if you don't know `operate()`)
- A marker for their place (You can't have them, if you don't know how `operate()` will work on them)

If you have at least some insight into `operate()`, this becomes something between solvable and easy:

- If `operate($a . $b)==operate($a) . operate($b)`, then you just split your original input by the labels, run the non-label parts through `operate()`, but obviously not the labels, then reassemble
- If `operate()` is guaranteed to let a placeholder string, that itself is guaranteed to be not part of the normal input ("\0" and friends come to mind) alone, then you extract your labels in order, replace them by the placeholder, run the result through `operate()` and later replace the placeholder by your saved labels (in order)

**Edit**

After reading your comments, here are some lines of code

```
$input = "string with {LABELS} between brackets {HERE} and {HERE}";

//Extract labels and replace with \0
$tmp=preg_split('/(\{.*?\})/',$input,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$labels=array();
$txt=array();
$islabel=false;
foreach ($tmp as $t) {
  if ($islabel) $labels[]=$t;
  else $txt[]=$t;
  $islabel=!$islabel;
}
$txt=implode("\0",$txt);

//Run through operate()
$txt=operate($txt);

//Reasssemble
$txt=explode("\0",$txt);
$result='';
foreach ($txt as $t)
  $result.=$t.array_shift($labels);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. See my reply to the first comment and also have a look at the updated operate(). Does this give the necessary insight?

Comment: AFAIKS it leaves `\0` alone, so if you are sure there are no `\0` in the original string, the second option above will work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, what does \0 mean? The input string will always only contain a-zA-Z {} with possibly other characters between those brackets (such as {bracket:2344}) but they are filtered out before anyway.

Comment: "\0" in PHP is the character with the ordinal 0. It is unprintable, and in other languages (C most often) it just amrks the end of a string. It is never part of a human-readable string, if you consider C developers to not be humans, which is an arguable proposition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do as a first attempt. Split your string into single words, then feed them into operate() one by one, depending on whether the word is 'braced' or not.

```
$input = "string with {LABELS} between brackets {HERE} and {HERE}";
$inputArray = explode(' ',$input);
foreach($inputArray  as $key => $value) {
  if(!preg_match('/^{.*}$/',$value)) {
     $inputArray[$key] = operate($value);
  }
}
$output = implode(' ',$inputArray);
```

Comment: Since operate() is a POS-tagger (see my comment on the first reply and updated operate()) I need to feed the entire string (without labels) to operate() at once. To feed it word-by-word is not an option.